# MS Excel: Match Value With Two Criterias & Distribute Them Across a Timeline

Tags: excel, gantt-chart

I'm not very well versed with Macros and could use a little help. I have a dataset with three columns,

- Customer ID
- Date of Purchase
- Amount

I want to plot this on a linear timeline, date wise, to create a GANTT visual. So the macro should lookup the date, match it with the customer ID, and return the amount. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am attaching an image for more clarity. Thanks :-)

Image Attached:

[image]

Comment: You can do this without code by using a PivotTable:  Select your data range A1:C8 From the pull-down menus >> Insert >> PivotTable  Your range should already be selected, in the next area below, Select 'Existing Location' and select the area where you want your data to be: E2:K8 - OK.  In the PivotTable fields, drag CustomerID to Columns and Amount and Date to 'Vaulkes'.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel are you using?

If it's one that supports the FILTER function you could use a formula like this.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!$C$3:$C$8, (Sheet1!$A$3:$A$8=$E3)*(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8=F$2)),0)
```

That would go in F3 and be copied across and down.

If you are using an earlier version you could use this formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$8=$E3)*($B$3:$B$8=F$2)*($C$3:$C$8))
```

Comment: For `SUMPRODUCT()` second condition you can use `$B$3:$B$8=F$2` instead of `$A$3:$B$8=F$2`

Comment: That was a typo, that for some strange reason didn't stop the formula working.

Comment: Because `SUMPRODUCT()` check and compare each cell and when not match just consider as 0.

Comment: I know what SUMPRODUCT does, and with the typo it could have given incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX/MATCH` in this way.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$8,MATCH($E3&F$2,$A$3:$A$8&$B$3:$B$8,0)),"")
```

With <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> you can try `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP($E3&F$2,$A$3:$A$8&$B$3:$B$8,$C$3:$C$8,"")
```

[image]